# Thanking someone for their email

Tags: formality, email, greetings

I run a business and answer several emails a day. I tend to interact with people in an informal way.
On their first message, I always put *"Thank you for messaging me"* in the first line of a reply, which I always thought was grammatically correct. The more I think of it, the more it sounds like *"I'm glad you keep messaging me"*, which doesn't make sense and may sound sarcastically.

Which one would be more correct here then:

- Thank you for messaging me,
- Thank you for your message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either of these is appropriate, but the terms "message" and "messaging" are evolving in common usage to have a connotation of text messaging or social media messaging (e.g. facebook messaging). 
So someone might get your email "Thank you for your message" and go looking for a text you sent them previously.
You could avoid any ambiguity by just writing "Thank you for your email".

[From Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=message%20me) message me:
To ask someone to send you a short SMS-type message from one mobile device to another. Telling a person to "message me" is the same as saying "text me", but sounds a lot cooler, and has a nicer ring to it.
Guy: "Message me when the movie is over and we'll connect over coffee."
Girl: "Will do!"